# JSON parser: avoid metadata

Tags: java, json

I have simple json parser. I am newbie so please don't answer in hard way...

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class ParseJsonFaculties
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://somesite/";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(url);

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                JSONArray id = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Id");
                Iterator<String> iteratorId = id.iterator();
                while (iteratorId.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(iteratorId.next());
                }

                JSONArray name = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Name");
                Iterator<String> iteratorName = name.iterator();
                while (iteratorName.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(iteratorName.next());
                }

        JSONArray sname = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("ShortName");
        Iterator<String> iteratorSname = sname.iterator();
        while (iteratorSname.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iteratorSname.next());
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

And after running it I get this error:

```
org.json.simple.parser.ParseException: Unexpected character (h) at position 0.
```

This happens, as I think, because of json response from server, it actually looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 4559
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2016 08:53:40 GMT

[{json here}]
```

How to avoid metadata if this is a case?

Thanks.

================

Solved by re-writing the code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class UniverisFacultiesReciever {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String urlString = "https://somesite/";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String result = "";
            String output = "";
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result + output;
            }

            conn.disconnect();


            //start parse.

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = obj.getString("Id");
        String name = obj.getString("Name");
        String shortname = obj.getString("ShortName");
        System.out.println("Faculty ID: ");
        System.out.print(id);
        System.out.println("Faculty name: ");
        System.out.print(name);
        System.out.println("Faculty short name: ");
        System.out.print(shortname);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Sorry for such a bad code, it is still WIP.

Comment: You are using it wrong. You are not suppose to call the parse on the URL. You need to retrieve the content and than run parse. Look at the following example for reference [https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/)

Comment: I haven't used this `org.json` library before, and I want to help you. So I'd really appreciate that if you can specify the version of `org.json` you are using.

Comment: @kenshinji thanks but I have figured it out :) I am retrieving and then parsing with built-in org.json. Thank you guys for help.

Comment: @NapoleonTheCake, please answer your question and paste the code so it will be for future people who sees this question.